# Pass array as inputs to Azure DevOps YAML file

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am testing a scenario where I will be auto triggering multiple jobs and will take it as an input as an array. Below is my code where I am getting error stating    `/template.yml (Line: 21, Col: 3): Key not found 'repos'`

Below is my code that i am testing.

```
# batch.yml

## template.yml##

trigger:
- d94-Develop
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

## ESSA Prod Websites ##

steps:
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
  - name : branchName
        displayName: BRANCH_NAME
        values:
        - $(Build.SourceBranchName)
  - name : repos
        displayName: REPOSITORY_NAME
        values:
    - 'app-essa-abc-fr'
    - 'app-essa-abc-tr'
```

```
parameters:
- name: branchName
  type: string
  default: ''

steps:
- ${{ each repo in parameters.repos }}:
  - task: TriggerPipeline@1
    displayName: 'Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline: Build'
    inputs:
      serviceConnection: 'Azure_DevOps_API_Connection'
      project: ABC
      Pipeline: 'Build'
      buildDefinition: '${{ repo }}-build-k8s'
      buildRepo: '${{ repo }}'
      Branch: '${{ parameters.branchName }}'

  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'sleep 120'
```

Comment: The indentation doesn't seem correct when you are passing in the parameters, verify the YAML file using a validator as well.

Comment: You don't have repos parameter in the template, you send a parameter you didn't declare.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments your indentation is off as well as properly declaring your parameters. You will need to pass in the list as on object, define it as such and recommend defaulting the parameters. Something similar to:

```
parameters:
- name: branchNames
  type: object
  default:['app-essa-abc-fr', 'app-essa-abc-tr']
```

Then pass in the object `brachNames`

Here is are some blog posts with references:

[YAML Objets](https://blog.johnfolberth.com/advanced-azure-devops-yaml-objects/)

[Leveraging YAML Objects with Templates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/azure-devops-pipelines-leveraging-stages-with-yaml-objects/ba-p/3719136)